# extjs tabpanel needs two click on tab in mozilla firefox browser

Tags: javascript, extjs, tabpanel

I have created tabpanel in Extjs. The tab needs two clicks to switch from one tab to another tab in firefox. But it works with single click in other browsers like chrome and ie.

Any workaround for this issue much appreciated.

I have created a sample code in the fiddle.
[click here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/18vv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just checked your fiddle solution working good with `ExtJS 5.1.1` .Look like some issue with `ExtJS 5.1.0`

Found this link on Sencha forum related to your issue [**Workaround**](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?294953-Tab-switching-bug)

Comment: Our parent project uses the 5.1.0 classic theme version. So i have to use the 5.1.0. Please suggest a workaround for this issue.

Comment: @kalidoss The workaround would be to either update your framework version or [to backport all the bugfixes](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/whats_new/release_notes.html). That's 97 bugfixes for Grid alone (and 93 more for 5.1.2). Have fun.

Comment: Thanks for your workaround. You can find the working solution here [link](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1ave)